# PostSharp and aspect inheritance through hierarchy

Tags: c#, inheritance, interface, aop, postsharp

According to PostSharp documentation, aspect inheritance should be among others supported on:

> Parameter or Return Value of an abstract, virtual or interface method

But in my case it doesn't seem to support inheritance when those supported elements are combined. I have this minimal code to reproduce the issue:

```
public interface IData { }

public interface ITest
{
    void DoSomething([Required] IData data);
}

public abstract class AbstractTest : ITest
{
    public abstract void DoSomething(IData data);
}

public class Test : AbstractTest
{
    public override void DoSomething(IData data)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Building this code ends with:

> PostSharp.Patterns.Contracts.RequiredAttribute" cannot be applied to
>   method
>   "PostSharpInheritance.AbstractTest.DoSomething(PostSharpInheritance.IData)@data"
>   because it is abstract.

If I move the `Required` attribute from interface to to abstract method the compilation will succeed. If I place the `Required` attribute in both interface and abstract method I will get the same error.

How am I supposed to place attributes (contracts) on interface without loosing option for using abstract classes in class hierarchy implementing that interface?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example code from the question should work as described in the documentation. The problem is caused by a bug in PostSharp code, which has been reported to PostSharp team. The fix will be implemented in one of the upcoming builds of version 3.1.

**Update:** This bug has been fixed in the PostSharp build 3.1.33.